# How to get Tomcat version number in Java

Tags: java, tomcat, version

How do I get the Tomcat/Catalina version number in JAVA?

I've seen lots of how to do it via command line etc. but that's not code I can use, I also cannot use catalina.path as the version number has been stripped from the path.

Please also note I want to use the version in code, so the various JSP solutions that I've looked at also do not work for me.

Thanks

Comment: http://www.bestdesigns.co.in/blog/check-jsp-tomcat-version

Comment: and here is your answer :http://www.indianwebportal.com/check-jsp-tomcat-version

Comment: Apologies but doesn't actually answer my question...how do I do it in Java.  I do not want to access a page.  I need this in code because other code segments are dependent on whether version 6 or version 7 is being used.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### From a JSP

In a jsp file you can print out the version like this:

```
Tomcat Version : <%= application.getServerInfo() %>
```

Output:

```
Tomcat Version : Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
```

### Outside of JSP (Any Java Code)

If you want it outside of a JSP (e.g. in a Servlet or listener or w/e) take a look at the [`org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.html) class, it has some nice static methods:

```
System.out.println(ServerInfo.getServerBuilt());
System.out.println(ServerInfo.getServerInfo());
System.out.println(ServerInfo.getServerNumber());
```

Output:

```
Sep 24 2014 09:01:51
Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
8.0.14.0
```

So what you really want is `ServerInfo.getServerNumber()`.

**Note:**

The `ServerInfo` class also has a `main()` method so it can be run as a standalone application too:

```
java -cp lib/catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
```

Example output:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.14
Server built:   Sep 24 2014 09:01:51
Server number:  8.0.14.0
OS Name:        Windows 7
OS Version:     6.1
Architecture:   x86
JVM Version:    1.7.0_55-b13
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Comment: he can just run java -cp catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo

Comment: @MihaiC mr. Sean said's that "I've seen lots of how to do it via command line etc. but that's not code I can use," so he need something that he can use. e.g. for verifying the server something like that :)

Comment: @Secondo Sean said just now : "Apologies but doesn't actually answer my question...how do I do it in Java. I do not want to access a page. I need this in code because other code segments are dependent on whether version 6 or version 7 is being used."

Comment: @MihaiC I just read that comment, sorry dude.

Comment: Also found the official javadoc for [ServerInfo](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this in your JSP `<%= application.getServerInfo() %>` [Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925073/how-to-find-out-running-tomcat-version)