# How to check tomcat version in java

Tags: java, command

How can I excecute command in java to find the version of the 
     tomcat installed in java programming. I tried using command java -cp 
    .catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo but I am unable to 
     understand to give the path of the tomcat installed directory

```
        String line1;
          BufferedReader input1;
          Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {
                "cmd /c start cmd.exe /K java -cp catalina.jar 
                 org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo /s" });

          input1 = new BufferedReader(new 
          InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()));
          while ((line1 = input1.readLine()) != null) {
          System.out.println(line1);

        }
        input1.close();
```

I need to print version of the tomcat installed using commands in java

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Tomcat version number in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244947/how-to-get-tomcat-version-number-in-java?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods of class [`ServerInfo`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/util/ServerInfo.html):

> Simple utility module to make it easy to plug in the server identifier when integrating Tomcat.

As follow:

```
// Return the server built time for this version of Tomcat.    
System.out.println(ServerInfo.getServerBuilt());

// Return the server identification for this version of Tomcat.
System.out.println(ServerInfo.getServerInfo());

// Return the server's version number.
System.out.println(ServerInfo.getServerNumber());
```

Comment: Thank you, please suggest how to load ServerInfo class in my program