# Cloud foundry java buildpack - find out tomcat version

Tags: tomcat, cloud-foundry, buildpack

I know there is documentation or release notes, but is there any way I can find out tomcat version that cloud foundry uses inside any env variables?

I don't see it in /actuator/env

Answer (score 1):

From the Cloud Foundry side, you can see what's installed by the Java buildpack during staging. It show's you exactly what's been installed. This doesn't get saved anywhere though, unless you're sending your application logs to some form of permanent storage.

Ex:

```
   -----> Java Buildpack v4.19 (offline) | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#3f4eee2
   -----> Downloading Jvmkill Agent 1.16.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/jvmkill/bionic/x86_64/jvmkill-1.16.0_RELEASE.so (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_202 from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/openjdk/bionic/x86_64/openjdk-jre-1.8.0_202-bionic.tar.gz (found in cache)
          Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (2.3s)
          JVM DNS caching disabled in lieu of BOSH DNS caching
   -----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 3.13.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/memory-calculator/bionic/x86_64/memory-calculator-3.13.0_RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
          Loaded Classes: 8166, Threads: 250
   -----> Downloading Client Certificate Mapper 1.8.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/client-certificate-mapper/client-certificate-mapper-1.8.0_RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Container Security Provider 1.16.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/container-security-provider/container-security-provider-1.16.0_RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> **Downloading Tomcat Instance 9.0.17** from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/tomcat/tomcat-9.0.17.tar.gz (found in cache)
          Expanding Tomcat Instance to .java-buildpack/tomcat (0.6s)
   -----> Downloading Tomcat Access Logging Support 3.3.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/tomcat-access-logging-support/tomcat-access-logging-support-3.3.0_RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Tomcat Lifecycle Support 3.3.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/tomcat-lifecycle-support/tomcat-lifecycle-support-3.3.0_RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
   -----> Downloading Tomcat Logging Support 3.3.0_RELEASE from https://java-buildpack.cloudfoundry.org/tomcat-logging-support/tomcat-logging-support-3.3.0_RELEASE.jar (found in cache)
```

If you're looking to get it from inside the container or inside the app, the suggestions in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27245117/1585136) should work.

Hope that helps!