# tomcat X-Frame-Options or antiClickJackingEnabled

Tags: webserver, tomcat7, cross-domain

I am looking for an answer strictly for tomcat webserver. I am need to call a different domain using iframe and it is giving the following error in internet explorer

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame To help protect the
>   security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of
>   this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

I know this is cross domain issue and i am trying to enable it in tomcat webserver. I have search internet for a day and i dont see a clear answer on how to configure either X-Frame-Options or antiClickJackingEnabled

I used the following option in web.xml but it did not work

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
                <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
        <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
                <param-value>[https://subdomain1.example.com][https://subdomain2.example.com][https://subdomain3.example.com]</param-value>
        </init-param>
</filter>
```

Please help!!!

Comment: can you see any errors in the tomcat logs?

Comment: After inspecting inspecting logs I saw `ClassNotFound` exception which led me to conclusion that Tomcat version I used did not have HttpHeaderSecurityFilter feature yet. Pointed out by Max 23 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991226/xframe-option-in-tomcat-7#answer-35795122

Answer (score 3):

You can't create two filters. Join the structure.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
            <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
            <param-value>[https://subdomain1.example.com][https://subdomain2.example.com][https://subdomain3.example.com]</param-value>
    </init-param>
 </filter>
```

Answer (score 2):

did you enable the filter:

```
  <!-- The mapping for the HTTP header security Filter -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```