# configuring Content-Security-Policy in tomcat

Tags: security, tomcat, content-security-policy, clickjacking

I read about configuring/implementing Content-Security-Policy header and I came accross 2 ways of doing it:

1. using custom filter that implements Filter as given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306300/can-tomcat-7-be-configured-to-insert-content-security-policy-http-header) link
2. using meta tag

Please note that this question is not duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306300/can-tomcat-7-be-configured-to-insert-content-security-policy-http-header), Iam looking for a solution better than given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306300/can-tomcat-7-be-configured-to-insert-content-security-policy-http-header) link

I see the drawbacks in (1) is its driven through code, not through a configuration file , drawbacks in option (2) is if I have say 100 html files, I need to put this tag in every HTML? (correct me if I'm wrong)
The solution I'm looking for is something I can configure in web.xml and becomes applicable for all the html files. Something the way we do in case of configuring X-Frame-Options in web.xml like given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991226/xframe-option-in-tomcat-7), don't we have similar way of configuring Content-Security-Policy in web.xml ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Tomcat 7 be configured to insert "Content-Security-Policy" HTTP header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306300/can-tomcat-7-be-configured-to-insert-content-security-policy-http-header)

Comment: Its not duplicate, option(1) i specified is from the topic you shared above.Please read drawbacks i have explained above, Iam looking for a solution wherein we can configure it using web.xml or any other tomcat configuration file

Answer (score 9):

### Configure content-security-policy in web.xml

You can use the recommendation provided by `OWASP` [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Content_Security_Policy). It is a web filter that you can implement in your backend.

The below filter has to be then defined in your `web.xml` file. This gets called on every request in your application. In java you may do that by creating an appropriate class.

```xml
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ContentSecurityPolicy</filter-name>
        <filter-class>YourPackagePath.ContentSecurityPolicyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ContentSecurityPolicy</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

The above will implement the below values for content-security-policy in your HTTP Header

> *default-src 'none'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; form-action 'self'; reflected-xss block*

Comment: Updated the link to a newer one providing the JAVA implementation of CSP

Comment: Link is dead, try https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/Content_Security_Policy

Comment: Thanks @Kamal, I have updated the link in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using https://github.com/sourceclear/headlines (dead link, this is all I could find: https://github.com/stevespringett/headlines) ? It's goal is to make security-related headers a matter of configuration instead of code like you ask.

```
{
  "XContentTypeConfig": {
    "enabled": true
  },

  "XFrameOptionsConfig": {
    "enabled": true,
    "value":"DENY"
  },

  "XssProtectionConfig": {
    "enabled": true
  },

  "HstsConfig": {
    "enabled": true,
    "includeSubdomains":true,
    "maxAge":31536000
  },

  "CspConfig": {
    "csp": {
      "default-src":["'self'"]
    },
    "cspReportOnly":{}
  },

  ... snip
}
```

Comment: The Github link shared in your answer is not valid.

Comment: Strange, the repo is gone. I added https://github.com/stevespringett/headlines which appears to be the same content