# Does Apache Tomcat 8.5.51 support content-security-policy header

Tags: tomcat

I have done as per below link but it thrown error 'http 404 not found'

[configuring Content-Security-Policy in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242697/configuring-content-security-policy-in-tomcat)

Did I missed anything?

Thank you

Comment: Is tomcat started? Does any other app work on it? Any error in startup logs?