# checking tomcat version on the server for ansible

Tags: java, tomcat, ansible

Need to verify tomcat's version on the server while running ansible playbooks. The only way I know to do that is:

```
[root@server ~]# cd /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/
[root@server bin]# ./version.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/share/tomcat8
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/share/tomcat8/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Server version: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
Server built:   Dec 1 2015 22:30:46 UTC
Server number:  8.0.30.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-504.1.3.el6.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_66-b17
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Is there any other way? This one isn't the nicest one since even the directory of this version.sh script changes depending on tomcat version and there is a lot of parsing to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find out running tomcat version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925073/how-to-find-out-running-tomcat-version)

Answer (score 1):

there are several ways to do this you can find them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925073/how-to-find-out-running-tomcat-version)

> 1. open http://localhost:8080/ in your web browser and version should be visible there.
> 2. execute the version.sh script in your tomcat/bin directory.
> 3. you can check it in release notes.
> 4. you can also check the version through `java -cp catalina.jar org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo`

source: [how to find out running tomcat version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14925073/how-to-find-out-running-tomcat-version)

Comment: If you know it is a duplicate mark it as so and don't re-answer the same question.

Answer (score 0):

`./version.sh` calls

`./catalina.sh version`

which calls

```
java  -classpath "$CATALINA_HOME/lib/catalina.jar" org.apache.catalina.util.ServerInfo
```